# Unit test using Moq for paging and sorting in C# returns at least one object must implement IComparable

Tags: c#, linq, unit-testing, moq, linq-to-objects

I've implemented paging and sorting (by multiple columns) in C# and Moq. Now I want to create a unit test for it but I'm getting the error:

"At least one object must implement IComparable".

I've already implemented IComparable in the Log object, but I keep getting that error message.

I know the problem comes from the OrderBy, ThenByDescending, etc. But I thought that implementing IComparable in Log would be enough to fix it.

Anyways, There I'm comparing just the Ids, but I should be able to compare by whatever sortColumns has, maybe creating one comparer per column, but first I must know how to make it work.

Any advice?

This is my code:

**Snippet from the unit test.**

```
logRepository.Setup(p => p.All()).Returns(logs.AsQueryable); 
var logService = new LogService { PrivateLoggingCatalog = catalog.Object };     
var logsReturned = logService.SearchLogs(null, null, 1, 10, new List<string>{"Message"}, new List<string>{"desc"}).Items.ToList();
```

**LogService**

```
public class LogService : ILogService
{
    public PageOf<Log> SearchLogs(DateTime? from, DateTime? to, int pageNumber, int pageSize, IEnumerable<string> sortColumns, IEnumerable<string> sortDirections, string searchTerm = null)
    {
        var filteredData = PrivateLoggingCatalog.LogRepository.All()
                   .Where(x => (!from.HasValue || x.Date >= from)
                       && (!to.HasValue || x.Date < to));

        filteredData = FilterLogBySearchTerm(filteredData, searchTerm);

        return PageSortResult(filteredData, pageNumber, pageSize, sortColumns.ToList(), sortDirections.ToList());
    }

    private static IQueryable<T> FilterLogBySearchTerm<T>(IQueryable<T> filteredData, string searchTerm)
        where T : Log
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchTerm))
        {
            filteredData = filteredData.Where(x => x.Level.Contains(searchTerm) ||
                                x.Message.ToUpper().Contains(searchTerm) ||
                                x.MachineName.ToUpper().Contains(searchTerm) ||
                                x.CallSite.ToUpper().Contains(searchTerm) ||
                                x.Exception.ToUpper().Contains(searchTerm) ||
                                x.Stacktrace.ToUpper().Contains(searchTerm) ||
                                x.ErrorClass.ToUpper().Contains(searchTerm) ||
                                x.ErrorMessage.ToUpper().Contains(searchTerm) ||
                                x.ErrorMethod.ToUpper().Contains(searchTerm) ||
                                x.ErrorSource.ToUpper().Contains(searchTerm) ||
                                x.InnerException.ToUpper().Contains(searchTerm));
        }
        return filteredData;
    }

    private static PageOf<T> PageSortResult<T>(IQueryable<T> filteredData, int pageNumber, int pageSize, IList<string> sortColumns, IList<string> sortDirections) where T : Log
    {
        IOrderedQueryable<T> items = null;

        items = sortDirections[0] == "asc"
                        ? filteredData.OrderBy(SortColumns<T>()[sortColumns.ElementAtOrDefault(0)])
                        : filteredData.OrderByDescending(SortColumns<T>()[sortColumns.ElementAtOrDefault(0)]);

        var i = 1;

        if (sortDirections.Count > 1)
        {
            sortDirections.RemoveAt(0);
            items = sortDirections.Aggregate(items, (current, sortDirection) => sortDirection == "asc" ? 
                current.ThenBy(SortColumns<T>()[sortColumns.ElementAtOrDefault(i++)]) : 
                current.ThenByDescending(SortColumns<T>()[sortColumns.ElementAtOrDefault(i++)]));
        }

        items = items.ThenByDescending(SortColumns<T>()["Id"]);

        var result = new PageOf<T>
        {
            TotalItems = filteredData.Count(),
            Items = items.Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize)
        };

        return result;
    }

    static DictionaryWithDefault<string, Expression<Func<T, object>>> SortColumns<T>() where T : Log
    {
        return new DictionaryWithDefault<string, Expression<Func<T, object>>>(x => new { x.Id })
            {
                { "Id", x => new {x.Id} },
                { "Message", x => new {x.Message}},
                { "Level", x => new {x.Level}},
                { "Date", x => new {x.Date}},
                { "Logger", x => new {x.Logger}},
                { "MachineName", x => new {x.MachineName}},
                { "CallSite", x => new {x.CallSite}},
                { "Exception", x => new {x.Exception}},
                { "InnerException", x => new {x.InnerException}},
                { "Stacktrace", x => new {x.Stacktrace}},
                { "ErrorSource", x => new {x.ErrorSource}},
                { "ErrorClass", x => new {x.ErrorClass}},
                { "ErrorMethod", x => new {x.ErrorMethod}},
                { "ErrorMessage", x => new {x.ErrorMessage}}
            };
    }
```

**Snippet of Log.cs**

```
public class Log : Entity, IComparable
    {
      public int CompareTo(object other)
        {
            var log = (Log)other;
            if (this.Id > log.Id)
                return 1;

            if (this.Id < log.Id)
                return -1;

            return 0;
        }
}
```